# How to publish post with private status?

Tags: wordpress, vb.net, xml-rpc, joeblogs

I am using JoeBlogs https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs to publish my content from ASP.NET VB to wordpress. I am having some problems with posting my Post in Private Status instead of Public Status

Here is my code for creating a new Post Status:

```
Dim postStatus = New PostStatus()
```

And this (i tried both of it but none of it work for me)

```
postStatus = JoeBlogs.PostStatus.Private
postStatus = postStatus.Private
```

The result is just publish my Post Content with Public Status without any error, i tried to debugged it and cant find any problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
even in C# would help me alot!
ps. its my first time posting on stackoverflow sorry for any mistakes

**Edit #2**
This is my other field which is working fine.

```
 Dim post = New Post() 


post.DateCreated = DateTime.Now
post.Title = txtTitle.Text
post.Body = txtContent.Text

wp.NewPost(post, True)
```

wp.NewPost does not support postStatus.

Comment: How are you trying `postStatus` to something else? At the moment it sounds like you're just creating it in memory, but not actually doing anything with it.

Comment: this is just part of my code, my full code can post content and upload attachment to wordpress, all i need is just to post it in "Private Status"

Comment: Yeah, but if you just declare a variable called `postStatus`, how does the library know that the variable even exists, let alone that it needs to apply it to anything?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs/blob/5231529d67aa3e9bd87feca9df7fd6bb88203d4e/JoeBlogs/wrappers/MetaWeblogWrapper.cs#L37) the class you're using? It seems like you want `false`, not `true`. Or is private != draft?

Comment: yes private is not draft, thats not what i want, but thx for the help

Comment: I wonder if you might be better off finding a maintained library. The last update to the one you're using was in 2014 and the author last responded in 2018.

Comment: I Cant find any relevant library that can upload media and post content to wordpress from asp, thats why im using joeblogs which got few examples that i can follow up and modified .